# Problem modifying core function - class is not called

Tags: module, extensions, backend, core, class

I apologize in advance for this question has been treated many times, but I think I just need a personal trainer on this!

I am trying to modify the function `sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail` in **Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php**

```
 public function sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail()
    {
        $storeId = $this->getStoreId(); // ---->this is the line I need to change----<
        if (!$storeId) {
            $storeId = $this->_getWebsiteStoreId();
        }

        $this->_sendEmailTemplate(self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
            array('customer' => $this), $storeId);

        return $this;
    }
```

So I created a module called M2W_Password in local, it contains etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <M2W_Password>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </M2W_Password>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer>M2W_Password_Model_Customer_Customer</customer>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

And here is the updated function in **Model/Customer/Customer.php**

```
<?php

class M2W_Password_Model_Customer_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
{

    public function sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail()
    {
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        if (!$storeId) {
            $storeId = $this->_getWebsiteStoreId();
        }

        $this->_sendEmailTemplate(self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
            array('customer' => $this), $storeId);

        return $this;
    }

}

?>
```

I cleared the cache, checked that the module is in Magento list of modules in system/configuration/Advanced, but the fix I put in my function is still not working.

EDIT --------------------------------

I just found out that another module extends the MAge_Customer_Model_Customer class. So here is my new class for Customer.php

class M2W_Password_Model_Customer_Customer extends Magestore_Onestepcheckout_Model_Customer_Customer
 {

But still it doesn't work. Which is weird because when I put the actual code I'm trying to implement directly in the other module Customer.php it works

Comment: By the way, my fix works when I modify the core function directly

Comment: Have you create M2W_Password.xml to app/etc/modules?

Comment: need to check compiler enable or not? also require to check any module rewrite thar class

Comment: Thanks guys, I forgot to mention that I had my module declared in app/etc/modules. So no success on that front. @AmitBera what do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out how to resolve the clash.

here is Customer.php

```
<?php
 class M2W_Password_Model_Customer_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
 {
    public function sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail()
    {

            $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
            if (!$storeId) {
              $storeId = $this->_getWebsiteStoreId();
            }

    $this->_sendEmailTemplate(self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
        array('customer' => $this), $storeId);

    return $this;
    } 
 }
```

And I modified the class in the other module with them calling my class

```
class Magestore_Onestepcheckout_Model_Customer_Customer extends M2W_Password_Model_Customer_Customer
{
```

I then commented out the rewrite tag of my module M2W/Password/etc/config.xml

```
    <models>
            <customer>
                <!-- <rewrite>
                    <customer>M2W_Password_Model_Customer_Customer</customer>
                </rewrite> -->
            </customer>
    </models>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your config.xml

`<models>
  <password>
     <class>M2W_Password_Model</class>
     <resourceModel>password_mysql4</resourceModel>
  </password>
  <customer>
     <rewrite>
      <customer>M2W_Password_Model_Customer_Customer</customer>
     </rewrite>
  </customer>
</models>`

Comment: Thanks HarryP, AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd offered the same solution, but it doesn't change anything. Why do you guys add the password tag?

Comment: Password tag specifies the model namespace.

Answer (score 0):

To create custom module follow the below steps:

Step 1:- **app\etc\module\M2W_Password.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<M2W_Password>
  <active>true</active>
    <codePool>local</codePool>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
</M2W_Password>
</modules>
</config>
```

Step 2:- **app\code\local\M2W\Password\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<M2W_Password>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
</M2W_Password>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
      <password>
            <class>M2W_Password_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>password_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </password>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer>M2W_Password_Model_Customer_Customer</customer>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
    </models>
</global>
```

Step 3:- **app\code\local\M2W\Password\Model\Customer\Customer.php**

```
 <?php
 class M2W_Password_Model_Customer_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
 {
    public function sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail()
    {
            //echo "Come Here"; 
            //exit; 
            $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
            if (!$storeId) {
              $storeId = $this->_getWebsiteStoreId();
            }

    $this->_sendEmailTemplate(self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
        array('customer' => $this), $storeId);

    return $this;
    } 
 }
```

Please clear cache and check frontend.

Comment: Thanks @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd but it still doesn't work, when I uncomment echo "come here" I don't get anything. Any idea?

Comment: @AnthoNy If you have followed proper folder structure (as we have provided) then this issue should be resolved, as we have tried on local.

Comment: Hi, It has worked but the module created was conflicting with another one that we use. If you check my question you'll see that I edited it and I also provided an answer. Thanks for your help!